# Maven - Spring - Error during ServletContainerInitializer processing

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, runtime-error

I'm actually working with Maven, Spring and Tomcat 8. The thing is that I'm trying to deploy an application that I've developed on this Tomcat server. 2 weeks ago, I was able to deploy it without problems. Now the thing is that I spent 2 days trying to resolve an error while deploying the application.

I really need some help here... I tried so many solutions but none worked. Hope you'll find one.

Here is the error :

```
26-Jun-2018 13:37:25.722 INFO [localhost-startStop-8] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR DΘploiement de l'archive C:\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\api.war de l'application web
26-Jun-2018 13:38:17.464 INFO [localhost-startStop-8] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
26-Jun-2018 13:38:17.578 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-8] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error during ServletContainerInitializer processing 
javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5244)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1812)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:155)
    ... 12 more

26-Jun-2018 13:38:17.579 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-8] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Erreur de dΘmarrage du contexte [/api] suite aux erreurs prΘcΘdentes
26-Jun-2018 13:38:17.595 INFO [localhost-startStop-8] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive C:\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\api.war has finished in 51á882 ms
```

I can provide the file pom.xml but it's quite huge because of the size of the app. Tell me if you need it.

**EDIT - Spring packages**

Here are the jar files for spring with it's version. There is only "spring-bridge" with another version because it does not exist in the last spring version. Still, even by commenting the dependency, the error still occur.

[Jar files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CifUz.png)

Comment: This suggests a version issue: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;

Comment: May be the problem is in some class without default constructor. Therefore, spring couldn't instantiate instance and context failed.

Comment: @duffymo 
Yes it's supposingly a problem with different versions. For more explaination, see my EDIT. It's all the same version.

Comment: @Maxim
What do you mean ? By having default constructor, this error may occur ?

Comment: Spring 5 is the newest reactive version.  Are you using reactive features?  If not, drop back to an earlier version of Spring 4.x

Comment: @duffymo i mean, that you u could overload constructor.

Comment: Never mix versions of a framework. The fact that something doesn't exists anymore is for a reason. Remove the `spring-bridge` dependency.

Comment: @duffymo How do I check if I am using reactive features ?

Comment: @M.Deinum The thing is that the jar file keeps appearing after the "clean install", even with the dependency and the jar files deleted before.

Comment: Then you haven't removed it. At least not in the correct wya.

Comment: If you have to ask if you're using reactive features, you probably aren't.

Comment: Whose constructor?  Surely you aren't proposing a modification to the Spring framework.  The answer is to use appropriate, consistent versions of the JARs.

Comment: @M.Deinum the thing is that I've tried to remove it several times (by doing `dependency:purge-local-repository` mostly) but it is still here.

Comment: Removing the dependency from your repository will obviously not help as long as it is part of your dependencies in your project.

Comment: I think that spring-bridge isn't the cause of my problem. spring-bridge comes from glassfish.hk2 and the dependency is only declared in files that I can't access like those from jersey.
@M.Deinum It's not part of my pom.xml file, that is why I don't really understand it's purpose.

Comment: Then the pom you linked to / posted isn't the actual pom you are using. The fact is you are mixing versions of jars from a framework which is always a bad idea (regardless of the framework) unless of course you want weird issues. Run `mvn dependency:tree` and see which dependencies are actually being pulled in and fix it.

Comment: I've just run `mvn dependency:tree | grep spring-bridge` to see that it is actually in the dependencies : `[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:spring-bridge:jar:2.5.0-b32:compile`. Again, I tried to delete it by going in the folder `.m2` and also by doing `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository - manualInclude="org.glassfish.hk2:spring-bridge"`, but it didn't worked. Don't know what to do with this dependency. @M.Deinum am I really doing it wrong ?

Comment: removing it from the repository doesn't remove it from your list of dependencies. It will just be downloaded again. As stated check your full dependencies and find the wrong versions.

Comment: But `spring-bridge` dependency is no longer in my pom.xml file. Do you mean that it could be in an other place than in the pom.xml file ?

Comment: The fact that it isn't in your direct dependencies doesn't mean it isn't a transitive dependency. As stated run `mvn dependency:tree` and check the version mismatches fix those.

Comment: I finally excluded `spring-bridge` from the dependency. But the error is still here (exactly the same as at the beginning). This dependency was apparently not the source of the problem.